# Laravel go-back dynamic button?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-routing

I want to implement a dynamic way of the go-back button in my Laravel project.

So I have this button:

```
<a href="WHAT TO DO HERE">
    <div class="go-back">
        <div class="go-back-inside">
            <h6 class="text">Go Back</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Which I have included on every page, what I want to do is to have one button that is included in all pages, and for instance, if I am on `bentley-flying-spur` and click on back I want to go to the prefix's base route (/) [services/cars/], or if I am on `riva` and click on the go-back-button to go to the base route (/) [services/yacht/];

The same button is included in both `bentley-flying-spur` and `riva` how can it dynamically go to the route group's (/)

```
Route::prefix('services')->group(function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('web.services');
    });
    Route::prefix('cars')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('web.modules.cars.products');
        });
        Route::get('/bentley-flying-spur', function () {
            return view('web.modules.cars.models.bentley-flying-spur');
        });
    });
    Route::prefix('yacht')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('web.modules.riva.products');
        });
        Route::get('/riva', function () {
            return view('web.modules.riva.models.riva');
        });
    });
}):
```

**DYNAMIC ROUTES**

```
Route::get('/', 'MainController@index');
Route::get('/services', 'MainController@services');
Route::get('/services/{service}', 'MainController@service');
Route::get('/services/{service}/{product}', 'MainController@product');
```

Comment: Like a browser's back button?! Don't use an `<a>` but a `<button>` and [window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history)

Comment: No, I do not want a browser's back button because if I have 2 types of cars, and first I click on BMW then go back to cars, and then I click on Rolls Royce and go Back again to cars, next back will be to BMW..

What I want to achieve is the back button to redirect me to the prefix group's base route so for cars, If I am on BMW and click on go back it will ledirect me to `/services/cars` and now if I click back it will link me to `services` so it goes to the top level group

Comment: Why would the "next back be to BMW" in that scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{{url(request()->route()->getPrefix())}}` in your href attribute.

What I would do is move the null routes out to the next prefix like below. I tested and it should work.

```
Route::prefix('services')->group(function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('web.services');
    });

    Route::get('/cars', function () {
        return view('web.modules.cars.products');
    });

    Route::get('/yacht', function () {
        return view('web.modules.riva.products');
    });

    Route::prefix('cars')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/bentley-flying-spur', function () {
            return view('web.modules.cars.models.bentley-flying-spur');
        });
    });

    Route::prefix('yacht')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/riva', function () {
            return view('web.modules.riva.models.riva');
        });
    });
});
```

Which I kind of think it cleans it up as well and is a little bit clearer.

Comment: Thank! Tried this one, it works but not in every scenario, it works for instance if I am on `services/cars/bmw-7` and click on go back it redirects me to `services/cars/` which is what I wanted, now on this screen I also have the go back button, what I want to do is it to link to `services/` how can I make that possible? Because if you take a look in the code above, I have **one main** group prefix **services** and inside have more groups, so if I am on `services/cars/` the back button should go to the upper level `services/`

Comment: Let me explain it more clearer:

Current URL: `services/cars/bmw-7` go back button links to -> `services/cars/`
Current URL: `services/cars` go back button links to -> `services/`
Current URL: `services` go back button links to -> `/`

Can this be achieved with one go-back button dynamically?

Comment: Okay, I will update. I did that from my phone.

Comment: Working as expected! Thank you!

Comment: Hello, I have updated my routes, so they are kinda more dynamic, added the updated routes above. Is there any way I can achieve the same thing with these new dynamic routes? Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, the more I look at this the less clean I think the approach gets. I would want to know more about your database and model structure before attempting to abstract this. Do you have a Car and Yacht, Product and Service Models? You probably want to be basing your controllers on your structure as well instead of having 1 controller to handle everything.

Comment: Okay, so there is no database included (because of the client's personal reasons), so the point is that there are services such as Car, Yacht, and each Service has it's own Products, like Cars have BMW 7, Bentley Flying Spur, etc. and there is a view for all services, for all products and one product. Because there is no DB we are using one Controller, and all of those data are stored in an array. However, the question is how we can fix the "go-back" button to work properly :) If you have any further questions, let me know

Comment: Any ideas on how to do it??